# A tricky bug in displaying associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, activerecord

There is a bug I got but can't find and solve. 
Here is what I have so far:
https://gist.github.com/2936556 this shows the model relations and the controller action.
https://gist.github.com/2936562 this shows the view template part for that action that triggers the bug

The bug is that somehow the message "forum.lines.notopics" is shown even if the forum does have topics. I have used the debugger gem to track things up, but the bugs seems kind'o random (when using the debugger it appears in most cases, withought it - always).

The log shows that there is no query to load the topics. 
Using @forum.topics instead of @topics does not make any difference at all.

Does anybody have any clues?

P.S. If some more info is needed, just ask. 
Rails 3.2.1, Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only idea is that Rails probably does not actually load `@topics` yet when you check it `<% if @topics.any? %>`.
Try to eager load topics

```
@forum = Forum::Forum.includes(:topics).find_by_id(params[:id])
```

(Anyway you probably need to do it, do you really need N+1 queries? :)

If it will not help, try to check for topics count instead of `@topics.any?`

```
<% if @forum.topics.count > 0 %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it seems to solve the trick, but the log still shows the Topics being loaded in a separate query. It is not that critical, but a clue on how to merge the queries will be most appreciated.